# ARM64 - GNU Assembler: Padding with NOP's to next label

Tags: arm64, gnu-assembler

Sorry, I don't know how to correctly formulate this question. But I will try it with a small example.
I'm searching for a directive in GAS to add a specific amount of padding instructions (NOP's) to the next label. The following example is a extract of the vector table for the AArch64 architecture. Each entry for the handler should be 32 instructions (128 bytes) long.

My goal:

```
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0:
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_syn:
    mov x0, #0x0
    bl _vec_handler_syn
    eret
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_irq:
```

Here I want, that GAS fill the table with the correct amount of NOP's after the `ERET` instruction to the next label `_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_irq`.

Is there a directive or macro in GAS to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The required directive is **.balgin**.

> **.balign[wl] abs-expr, abs-expr, abs-expr**
>
> Pad the location counter (in the current subsection) to a particular
>   storage boundary. The first expression (which must be absolute) is the
>   alignment request in bytes. For example `.balign 8' advances the
>   location counter until it is a multiple of 8. If the location counter
>   is already a multiple of 8, no change is needed.
>
> The second expression (also absolute) gives the fill value to be
>   stored in the padding bytes. It (and the comma) may be omitted. If it
>   is omitted, the padding bytes are normally zero. However, on some
>   systems, if the section is marked as containing code and the fill
>   value is omitted, the space is filled with no-op instructions.
>
> The third expression is also absolute, and is also optional. If it is
>   present, it is the maximum number of bytes that should be skipped by
>   this alignment directive. If doing the alignment would require
>   skipping more bytes than the specified maximum, then the alignment is
>   not done at all. You can omit the fill value (the second argument)
>   entirely by simply using two commas after the required alignment; this
>   can be useful if you want the alignment to be filled with no-op
>   instructions when appropriate.
>
> The .balignw and .balignl directives are variants of the .balign
>   directive. The .balignw directive treats the fill pattern as a two
>   byte word value. The .balignl directives treats the fill pattern as a
>   four byte longword value. For example, .balignw 4,0x368d will align to
>   a multiple of 4. If it skips two bytes, they will be filled in with
>   the value 0x368d (the exact placement of the bytes depends upon the
>   endianness of the processor). If it skips 1 or 3 bytes, the fill value
>   is undefined.

Quote from the [GAS manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC74)

The following works as excepted:

```
_vec_tbl_s:
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0:
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_syn:
    mov x0, #0x0
    bl _vec_handler_syn
    eret
.balign 128
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_irq:
    mov x0, #0x0
    bl _vec_handler_irq
    eret
.balign 128
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_fiq:
    mov x0, #0x0
    bl _vec_handler_fiq
    eret
.balign 128
_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_err:
    mov x0, #0x0
    bl _vec_handler_err
    eret
.balign 128
```

The disassembled binary:

```
$ aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d vector.o

vector.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_vec_tbl_cur_sp0>:
   0:   d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
   4:   940001ff        bl      800 <_vec_handler_syn>
   8:   d69f03e0        eret
   c:   d503201f        nop
  10:   d503201f        nop
  14:   d503201f        nop
  18:   d503201f        nop
  1c:   d503201f        nop
  20:   d503201f        nop
  24:   d503201f        nop
  28:   d503201f        nop
  2c:   d503201f        nop
  30:   d503201f        nop
  34:   d503201f        nop
  38:   d503201f        nop
  3c:   d503201f        nop
  40:   d503201f        nop
  44:   d503201f        nop
  48:   d503201f        nop
  4c:   d503201f        nop
  50:   d503201f        nop
  54:   d503201f        nop
  58:   d503201f        nop
  5c:   d503201f        nop
  60:   d503201f        nop
  64:   d503201f        nop
  68:   d503201f        nop
  6c:   d503201f        nop
  70:   d503201f        nop
  74:   d503201f        nop
  78:   d503201f        nop
  7c:   d503201f        nop

0000000000000080 <_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_irq>:
  80:   d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
  84:   940001e1        bl      808 <_vec_handler_irq>
  88:   d69f03e0        eret
  8c:   d503201f        nop
  90:   d503201f        nop
  94:   d503201f        nop
  98:   d503201f        nop
  9c:   d503201f        nop
  a0:   d503201f        nop
  a4:   d503201f        nop
  a8:   d503201f        nop
  ac:   d503201f        nop
  b0:   d503201f        nop
  b4:   d503201f        nop
  b8:   d503201f        nop
  bc:   d503201f        nop
  c0:   d503201f        nop
  c4:   d503201f        nop
  c8:   d503201f        nop
  cc:   d503201f        nop
  d0:   d503201f        nop
  d4:   d503201f        nop
  d8:   d503201f        nop
  dc:   d503201f        nop
  e0:   d503201f        nop
  e4:   d503201f        nop
  e8:   d503201f        nop
  ec:   d503201f        nop
  f0:   d503201f        nop
  f4:   d503201f        nop
  f8:   d503201f        nop
  fc:   d503201f        nop

0000000000000100 <_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_fiq>:
 100:   d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
 104:   940001c3        bl      810 <_vec_handler_fiq>
 108:   d69f03e0        eret
 10c:   d503201f        nop
 110:   d503201f        nop
 114:   d503201f        nop
 118:   d503201f        nop
 11c:   d503201f        nop
 120:   d503201f        nop
 124:   d503201f        nop
 128:   d503201f        nop
 12c:   d503201f        nop
 130:   d503201f        nop
 134:   d503201f        nop
 138:   d503201f        nop
 13c:   d503201f        nop
 140:   d503201f        nop
 144:   d503201f        nop
 148:   d503201f        nop
 14c:   d503201f        nop
 150:   d503201f        nop
 154:   d503201f        nop
 158:   d503201f        nop
 15c:   d503201f        nop
 160:   d503201f        nop
 164:   d503201f        nop
 168:   d503201f        nop
 16c:   d503201f        nop
 170:   d503201f        nop
 174:   d503201f        nop
 178:   d503201f        nop
 17c:   d503201f        nop

0000000000000180 <_vec_tbl_cur_sp0_err>:
 180:   d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
 184:   940001a5        bl      818 <_vec_handler_err>
 188:   d69f03e0        eret
 18c:   d503201f        nop
 190:   d503201f        nop
 194:   d503201f        nop
 198:   d503201f        nop
 19c:   d503201f        nop
 1a0:   d503201f        nop
 1a4:   d503201f        nop
 1a8:   d503201f        nop
 1ac:   d503201f        nop
 1b0:   d503201f        nop
 1b4:   d503201f        nop
 1b8:   d503201f        nop
 1bc:   d503201f        nop
 1c0:   d503201f        nop
 1c4:   d503201f        nop
 1c8:   d503201f        nop
 1cc:   d503201f        nop
 1d0:   d503201f        nop
 1d4:   d503201f        nop
 1d8:   d503201f        nop
 1dc:   d503201f        nop
 1e0:   d503201f        nop
 1e4:   d503201f        nop
 1e8:   d503201f        nop
 1ec:   d503201f        nop
 1f0:   d503201f        nop
 1f4:   d503201f        nop
 1f8:   d503201f        nop
 1fc:   d503201f        nop
```

Sorry, asked too quickly.